# Retinal blood vessel segmentation using Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I have the following retina image and I'm trying to trace the vessels (the darker lines coming out of the circle). Here is the original image:

[image]

I have tried thresholding the image using division normalization followed by filtering on contour area (as per a different stackoverflow solution):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the image
img = cv2.imread('retina_eye.jpg')

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# apply morphology
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT , (5,5))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# divide gray by morphology image
division = cv2.divide(gray, morph, scale=255)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(division, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU )[1] 

# invert
thresh = 255 - thresh

# find contours and discard contours with small areas
mask = np.zeros_like(thresh)
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

area_thresh = 10000
for cntr in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
    if area > area_thresh:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [cntr], -1, 255, 2)

# apply mask to thresh
result1 = cv2.bitwise_and(thresh, mask)
mask = cv2.merge([mask,mask,mask])
result2 = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('retina_eye_division.jpg',division)
cv2.imwrite('retina_eye_thresh.jpg',thresh)
cv2.imwrite('retina_eye_mask.jpg',mask)
cv2.imwrite('retina_eye_result1.jpg',result1)
cv2.imwrite('retina_eye_result2.jpg',result2)

# show results
cv2.imshow('morph', morph)  
cv2.imshow('division', division)  
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)  
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)  
cv2.imshow('result1', result1)  
cv2.imshow('result2', result2)  
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the final output I got:

[image]

It ended up tracing the vessels, but it also had some background noise.

Ideally I am looking for this output:

[image]

Any suggestions for achieving this result?

Comment: I'd invest time on getting better images first. what kind of imaging system is this? I don't see an algorithmic solution to this mess.

Comment: I second @Piglet here, the image quality is poor. I myself can't see all the vessels unless I see your expected output.

Comment: @Piglet Good point, I have updated the post with a higher quality image. The vessels are more visible now. Would love to hear your advice for it!

Comment: This is a very well studied problem, with hundreds of papers about it. I recommend you start with a literature search: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=retinal+vessel+segmentation

Comment: I think you want to see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62164546/vessel-segmentation-in-retina-image

Answer (score 0):

I have been researching the topic of retinal blood-vessel segmentation using deep learning and the question you asked is basically the same.
I would like to share my research with you.

In the cases where the part of images we want to segment has very low intensity or contrast, we have to apply **CLAHE (Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization)**. It is very powerful technique to get the very good results. I would like you to try it. Let me provide you some code for this also:

```
import cv2

bgr = cv2.imread(retinal_image)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8, 8))
equalized = clahe.apply(gray)
```

More over you can also use **Non Local Mean** for denoising the image.

If you want to know about the full process how it is done,  I would recommend you to go through [this easy paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/343049000_DEEP_LEARNING_BASED_RETINAL_VESSEL_SEGMENTATION_A_REVIEW) which covers the whole process.